Does COUNT(DISTINCT Col_Name) work in SFMC Query Studio?
I have a Data Extension with duplicate rows. When I run the following in Query Studio:
SELECT DISTINCT ContactID
from MyDataExtension
where Attr1='SomeValue'

I get around 1.1K records. If I skip the word DISTINCT I get 1.5K records.
Then if I try to just get the count for the above:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ContactID)
from MyDataExtension
where Attr1='SomeValue'

...I get 1.5K , exact same value that I get from the query without COUNT and DISTINCT
Is it a bug in QueryStudio ?

It may be good to summarize what was explained by both Jonas and EazyE as only this gives the full picture of the bug in QueryStudio and a workaround that can be used.
In this SQL code only Count2 will give the expected result:
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT ContactID) as Count1,
COUNT(DISTINCT (ContactID)) as Count2
from MyDataExtension

This is because QueryStudio reformats code for stability to:
SELECT
rtrim(left(coalesce(CAST(COUNT(ContactID) as char(255)),'<null>'), 255)) as count1,
rtrim(left(coalesce(CAST(COUNT(distinct (ContactID)) as char(255)),'<null>'), 255)) as count2
from MyDataExtension

The word DISTINCT will only be left when the attribute is enclosed in brackets in the original query.

That is a bug indeed.
Count(DISTINCT) is ignored in Query Studio, which doesn't execute your query as is, but actually reformats it quite substantially for stability;
You can verify this behavior as the created query is visible under Automation Studio / Activities.
I documented this example:
SELECT
count(DISTINCT concat(s.subscriberKey)) AS count
FROM
whatever

is turned to:
, rtrim(left(coalesce(CAST(count(concat(s.subscriberKey)) as char(255)),'<null>'), 255))  as count from whatever

note how there is no trace of DISTINCT in the result.

I think this works if I remeber my testing correctly
So don't use: Select Count (distinct EmailAddress) as Count
Instead, use: Select Count(distinct(EmailAddress)) as Count

you are right @EazyE - when applying the brackets - the COUNT(distinct (ContactID)) started to work fine in QueryStudio !
